# Azure - restore CosmosDB account using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cosmosdb, restore

I am trying to create a new Azure CosmosDB account in terraform account using:

**create_mode = "Restore"**

Basically I am trying to restore from an existing DB, and the code needs another input attribute, of the source DB:

**"source_cosmosdb_account_id"** = "/subscriptions/33f91226-e87e-4cdf67a1dae4e/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/locations/westeu/restorableDatabaseAccounts/test-source-db-name"

I am following the format indicated by the docs:

***The example is /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/locations/{location}/restorableDatabaseAccounts/{restorableDatabaseAccountName}***

However when I apply the code, I get the following error:

> Code="BadRequest" Message="Failed to parse uri
> /subscriptions/33f91226-e87e-4ca1dae4e/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/locations/westeu/restorableDatabaseAccounts/test-source-db-name

The issue seems to be the way I write the location inside the source ID, but I can't find any relevant info on how is the correct way.

I would really appreciate an example of **source_cosmosdb_account_id** if anyone did this successfully in terraform.

Thanks

Configuration used:

```
  backup = [
    {
      type                = "Continuous"
      interval_in_minutes = null
      retention_in_hours  = null
      storage_redundancy  = null
    }
  ]
  restore   = [
    {
      "source_cosmosdb_account_id" = "/subscriptions/33f6-e87e-4cdf-9480-7b1dae/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/locations/westeu/restorableDatabaseAccounts/test-source-db-name"
      "restore_timestamp_in_utc" = "2022-11-18T14:00:00.00Z"
      "database" = []
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you tried to restore

Comment: Added relevant code snippet in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently faced same issue and discovered that terraform documentation is outdated.

You need to have **create_mode = "Restore"**

Backup should be configured like this

```
  backup = [
    {
      type                = "Continuous"
      interval_in_minutes = 0
      retention_in_hours  = 0
      storage_redundancy  = "Geo"
    }
  ]
```

Format `/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/locations/{location}/restorableDatabaseAccounts/{restorableDatabaseAccountName}`
**is not correct**

Try with   `/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/locations/{location}/restorableDatabaseAccounts/{**instanceId**}`

You can find cosmos **instanceId** in json view
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue in my environment.
I got the same error ,   `Failed to parse uri /subscriptions/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/locations/westeu/restorableDatabaseAccounts/test-source-db-name`

with:

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {
  name                = "tfex-cosmos-db-31960"
  location            = "westus2"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "MongoDB"
 create_mode         =  "Restore"
 

restore {    source_cosmosdb_account_id=data.azurerm_cosmosdb_restorable_database_accounts.example.id
  source_cosmosdb_account_id="/subscriptions/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/locations/westeurope/restorableDatabaseAccounts/tfex-cosmos-db-31960?api-version=2022-05-15"
  restore_timestamp_in_utc="2022-11-25T22:06:00Z"
  
}
   

...
}
```

[image]

If I tried with `westeu` as the location you gave , in my case I am getting below error , as it must be westeurope as supported by azure .

[image]

Also please check

> Note from [cosmosdb_account | terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.31.0/docs/resources/cosmosdb_account#database): Database account
> with Continuous type (or  deleted account in last 30 days) are the
> restorable accounts and ***there cannot be Create/Update/Delete
> operations on the restorable database accounts***. ***`They can only be read and be retrieved by azurerm_cosmosdb_restorable_database_accounts.`***

- Restore the cosmos db account is supported in `azure portal , powershell,Azure CLI , ARM template` as in [restore-account-continuous-backup | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/restore-account-continuous-backup#restore-arm-template)

With `azurerm` provider , i can only read it through below with continuous backup type :

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {
  name                = "tfex-cosmos-db-31960"
  location            = "westus2"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "MongoDB"
 

  enable_automatic_failover = true
  

  capabilities {
    name = "EnableAggregationPipeline"
  }

  capabilities {
    name = "mongoEnableDocLevelTTL"
  }

  capabilities {
    name = "MongoDBv3.4"
  }

  capabilities {
    name = "EnableMongo"
  }

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "BoundedStaleness"
    max_interval_in_seconds = 300
    max_staleness_prefix    = 100000
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = "eastus"
    failover_priority = 0
  }



backup{

type = "Continuous"
//interval_in_minutes=60

}

data "azurerm_cosmosdb_restorable_database_accounts" "example" {
  name     = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db.name
  location = "West Europe"
}

output "name" {
  value=data.azurerm_cosmosdb_restorable_database_accounts.example.name
  
}
output "id" {
  value = data.azurerm_cosmosdb_restorable_database_accounts.example.id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Try checking the same with [azapi_resource block in terraform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts?source=recommendations&pivots=deployment-language-terraform)  :

as it requires parameters like api version , source account id which has to come from  cosmosdb_restorable_database_accounts
list and must form uri like `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/locations/West US/restorableDatabaseAccounts/d9b2xxx10d?api-version=2022-05-15` which is compatible in api resource.